# C++11 range-based for and map : readability

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, foreach, code-readability

The new range-based for loops really improve readability and are really easy to use. However, consider the following :

```
map<Foo,Bar> FooAndAssociatedBars;

for (auto& FooAndAssociatedBar : FooAndAssociatedBars) {
    FooAndAssociatedBar.first.doSth();
    FooAndAssociatedBar.second.doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

It may be a detail but I find it would have been more readable if I could have done something like :

```
for ( (auto& foo, auto& bar) : FooAndAssociatedBars) {
    foo.doSth();
    bar.doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

Do you know an equivalent syntax ?

**EDIT:**
Good news: C++17 has a proposal that adresses this problem, called structured bindings (see [1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf)). In C++17, you should be able to write:

```
tuple<T1,T2,T3> f(/*...*/) {
    /*...*/ 
    return {a,b,c};
}
auto [x,y,z] = f(); // x has type T1, y has type T2, z has type T3
```

which solves this readability problem

Comment: How would the compiler guess what `Foo` and `Bar` were meant to refer to?

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, foo is just a convenient way to say "name foo the left part of the std::pair". In absolute terms, it is possible to do this at compile time : this is just a notational convenience. I was wondering if it was possible to get such effect via overloading or something like that

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible to require the compiler to know about `std::pair` or to look for any struct with elements named `first` and `second`; that's rather specialized, and probably not appropriate for standardization. The next request would be for all the elements of a `tuple`...

Comment: @Pete: The OP's request does not seem so unreasonable (well, except for the type inference maybe): it is not so different than using `std::tie` to unpack a pair/tuple. The syntax could mean "define variables `foo` and `bar` before the loop (in this case as reference wrappers), and on each iteration do `tie(foo, bar) = *it`". It could be used in other places as well, for instance for unpacking the results of a function returning multiple values in a tuple: `(bool inserted, set<int>::iterator it) = mySet.insert(42);`. [...]

Comment: [...] I don't see any technical difficulties preventing this, but I guess tuples are not as ubiquitous in C++ as they are in other languages, so such syntax sugar is probably not essential.

Comment: @LucTouraille - `std::tie` is in the library, not the compiler. So this approach, too, requires the compiler to know more details about the standard library.

Comment: Well, I used `std::tie` only as an example of a possible implementation (that doesn't even work), but a compiler would be free to generate any code to provide this behavior. `begin` and `end` are also in the library, yet they are used to provide the range-based for loop syntax.

Comment: The syntax could be made to work with any type that support `std::get` (pairs, tuples, arrays, ...). The OP's code could be transformed into `for (auto & tmp : FooAndAssociatedBars) { auto & foo = std::get<0>(tmp); auto & bar = std::get<1>(tmp); ... }`; the sample code I gave could be transformed similarly: `auto & tmp = mySet.insert(42); bool inserted = std::get<0>(tmp); set<int>::iterator it = std::get<1>(tmp);`. This would even allow type inference.

Comment: @LucTouraille Yes, I was thinking of something of that kind. I still don't know if we can do it but we are getting closer...

Comment: @LucTouraille: Maybe you should write your thoughts into a standard proposal ;)

Comment: I understand what you're saying.. `first` and `second` aren't particularly useful names.  All you can do is use `const &` type assignments in the first 2 lines of your loop, like:  `for( pair<const int,int>& p : m )
  {
    const int& foo = p.first ;
    int& bar = p.second ;
    
  }`

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as you want. The closest is to declare variables inside the loop:

```
for (auto& FooAndAssociatedBar : FooAndAssociatedBars) {
    auto& foo = FooAndAssociatedBar.first;
    auto& bar = FooAndAssociatedBar.second;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea. Sooner or later, you would want the same for a `std::tuple`, and compiler should be able to use `std::get<>` on the `tuple` automatically. In my opinion your approach is pleasing you at the moment only, and you would find problems with this approach (assume it is implemented that way).

Standard committee has designed range-based for-loop with deep consideration. It is way better than `foreach` loop in other languages, and it is way shorter. Couple it with `auto&` and you are done!

Comment: "Not a good idea. Sooner or later, you would want the same for a std::tuple, and compiler should be able to use std::get<> on the tuple automatically." And the problem with that is?

Comment: More demands from the compiler.

Comment: How so? The way I see it any such language feature would be defined to call `std::get` (well unqualified `get` more likely) and therefore support `std::pair` and `std::tuple` and any user defined `tuple` like containers automatically.

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. You are demanding too much from compiler. And it adds complexity, ambiguity, more complex error messages, fight between different compiler vendors.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, you always have the possibility to use lambdas.

```
std::map<int, const char*> m { { 4, "hello" }, { 11, "c++" } };
convenient_for_each(m, [](int a, const char* b) {
    std::cout << b << a << std::endl;
  });
convenient_for_each(m, [](std::pair<int, const char> p) {
    std::cout << p.first << p.second << std::endl;
  });
```

Or wrapped as macro (not recommended)

```
FOREACH((int a, const char* b), m, std::cout << a << b << std::endl);
FOREACH((std::pair<int, const char*> p), m, std::cout << p.first << p.second << std::endl);
```

([Hackish sample implementation at LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3EhROV%240))

Auto won't work though, I'm still waiting for polymorphic lambdas. My approach is theoretically able to handle tuples as well.